# AWS Elasticsearch: How to update analyzer settings for existing index

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm trying to update settings for existing index with custom analyzer, but it is not allowing for open index, and aws is not allowing me to close the index.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS Elasticsearch only supports a subset of operations and indeed `_close` is not supported. You can get the list of supported operation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html).

Since you are updating an analyzer you will probably have to reindex your documents, so you can create a new index with the correct mapping and use [`_reindex`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) endpoint to copy the documents.

If you are not already doing it, I would advise you to use [index alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) to handle the index migration.